# Помогите пожалуйста!

Tags: python, csv, dict

Проблема проста, мой препод по программированию задал задание со словарями, ответ которого должен быть в одном словаре, но у меня не выходит, постоянно создаётся несколько словарей. Помогите товарищи, работа была с библиотекой CSV, код ниже:

```
import csv

data = []

with open(r'C:\Users\Jotaro Kujo\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\countries_1.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        data.append({'Страна': row['Страна'], 'Столица': row['Столица']})

print(data)код
```

Comment: В одном словаре это на верхнем уровне словарь, а на нижнем списки или как?

Answer (score 1):

Вы не описали ни задачу, ни формат CSV. Можно предположить следующее:

```
data = dict()
..
for row in reader:
    data[row['Страна']] = row['Столица']
```